# Shared Host VS Cloud server

Tags: cloud-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose between web hosting and cloud hosting?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-choose-between-web-hosting-and-cloud-hosting)

What the difference between a shared host and a cloud server.

I have a url http://domain.com and with a shared host, easly I have FTP details where I can upload everything on the server. Is is the same with cloud server or is it the same as amazon Cloudfront where you haven't got FTP details etc?

What are the differences in terms of speed?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The files on domain.com live on one physical machine whereas on Cloudfront they live on many servers around the world. When someone gets a file from Cloudfront comes from the nearest server to them. So it is designed to be quicker for the user.

I've answered your question about Cloudfront, but Amazon's other cloud services do different things, so if you want to know about the difference between those services, and a shared host then it's best to ask other questions.